# Cannot send objects through java ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization

I am creating a multiclient chat server program. Messages are sent as Message objects. The ServerClient class is not recieving the messages, though, and I don't know why.

Client:

```
package client;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.*;

import constraints.Constraints;
import message.Message;
import tools.Tools;
import window.ApplicationWindow;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Client extends ApplicationWindow {
    private static final int portNumber = 4444;

    private boolean send = false;

    private String userName;
    private String serverHost;
    private int serverPort;

    private GridBagLayout layout;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Constraints c_textArea;
    private JTextField textField;
    private Constraints c_textField;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String readName = System.getProperty("user.name");
        Client client = new Client(readName, portNumber);
        client.startClient();
    }

    private Client(String userName, int portNumber){
        super("ChatApp");
        Tools.setLookAndFeel();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.serverPort = portNumber;
        try {
    this.serverHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(layout);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setColumns(75);
        textArea.setRows(20);
        c_textArea = new Constraints(0,1);

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setVisible(true);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scroll, c_textArea);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(50);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                send = true;
            }
        });
        c_textField = new Constraints(0,2);
        add(textField, c_textField);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public void output(String message) {
        this.textArea.setText(this.textArea.getText() + "\n" + message);
    }

    private void startClient() {
        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(socket, userName, this);
            Thread serverAccessThread = new Thread(serverThread);
            serverAccessThread.start();
            while(serverAccessThread.isAlive() && this.isRunning()) {
                if (send) {
                    Message message = new Message(textField.getText(), "[" + "]", this.userName);
                    serverThread.addNextMessage(message);
                    send = false;
                    textField.setText("");
                }
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            output("Could not connect to server!");
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            output("Connection interrupted!");
        }
    }


    public void setHost(String serverHost) {
        this.serverHost = serverHost;
    }

}
```

ServerClient:

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import message.Message;

public class ServerClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter clientOut;
    private ChatServer server;

    private boolean running;

    public ServerClient(ChatServer server, Socket socket) {
        this.server = server;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.running = true;
    }

    private PrintWriter getWriter(){
        return clientOut;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.running;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{

            this.clientOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), false);
            clientOut.flush();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while(!socket.isClosed()){
                try {

                    if (in.available() > 0) {
                        Object i = in.readObject();
                        if (!i.equals(null)) {
                            Message input = (Message) i;
                            String message = input.getText();
                            String time = input.getTimestamp();
                            String user = input.getUser();

                            for(ServerClient thatClient : server.getClients()){
                                PrintWriter thatClientOut = thatClient.getWriter();
                                if(thatClientOut != null){
                                    thatClientOut.write(time + " " + user + ": " + message + "\r\n");
                                    thatClientOut.flush();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                } catch (SocketException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    break;
                }
            }

            in.close();
            this.stop();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //public void fileWrite()
}
```

ChatServer:

```
package server;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import constraints.Constraints;
import tools.Tools;
import window.ApplicationWindow;

import message.Message;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChatServer extends ApplicationWindow {

    private static final int portNumber = 4444;

    private ArrayList<Command> commands;

    private int serverPort;
    private String serverHost;
    private List<ServerClient> clients;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private GridBagLayout layout;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Constraints c_textArea;
    private JTextField textField;
    private Constraints c_textField;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ChatServer server = new ChatServer(portNumber);
        server.startServer();
    }

    public ChatServer(int portNumber){
        super("Server " + portNumber);
        this.serverPort = portNumber;
        try {
            this.serverHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            this.serverHost = "";
        }
        Tools.setLookAndFeel();

        initActions();

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(layout);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setColumns(75);
        textArea.setRows(20);
        c_textArea = new Constraints(0,1);

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setVisible(true);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scroll, c_textArea);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(50);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                process(textField.getText());
            }
        });
        c_textField = new Constraints(0,2);
        add(textField, c_textField);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public List<ServerClient> getClients(){
        return clients;
    }

    private void startServer(){
        clients = new ArrayList<ServerClient>();
        serverSocket = null;
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(this.serverHost);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort, 50, addr);
            acceptClients(serverSocket);
        } catch (IOException e){
            output("[ERROR] COULD NOT LISTEN ON PORT: " + serverPort);
            this.stop();
        }
    }

    private void acceptClients(ServerSocket serverSocket){

        output("[BEGIN] SERVER STARTING ON PORT: " + serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
        while (this.isRunning()) {
            try{
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                output("[ACCEPT] ACCEPTED CLIENT AT: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                ServerClient client = new ServerClient(this, socket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(client);
                thread.start();
                clients.add(client);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                output("[ERROR] ACCEPT FAILED ON: " + serverPort);
            }
        }
    }

    private void initActions() {
        this.commands = new ArrayList<Command>();
        this.commands.add(new Command() {
            public void run() {
                output("[COMMAND] IP: " + serverSocket.getInetAddress().toString());
            }

            public String getTrigger() {
                return "-ip";
            }
        });
        this.commands.add(new Command() {
            public void run() {

                for (ServerClient client : clients) {
                    if (!client.isRunning()) {
                        clients.remove(client);
                    }
                }

                output("[COMMAND] CLIENTS: " + clients.size());
            }

            public String getTrigger() {
                return "-clients";
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean process(String command) {
        for (Command c : this.commands) {
            if (c.getTrigger().equals(command)) {
                c.run();
                textField.setText("");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void output(String message) {
        this.textArea.setText(this.textArea.getText() + "\n" + message);
    }

}
```

ServerThread:

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import message.Message;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private String userName;
    private boolean isAlived;
    private final LinkedList<Message> messagesToSend;
    private boolean hasMessages = false;
    private Client client;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket, String userName, Client client){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.client = client;
        messagesToSend = new LinkedList<Message>();
    }

    public void addNextMessage(Message message) {
        synchronized (messagesToSend) {
            hasMessages = true;
            messagesToSend.push(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        print("Welcome :" + userName);
        print("Local Port :" + socket.getLocalPort());
        print("Server = " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream serverOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            serverOut.flush();
            ObjectInputStream serverIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while(!socket.isClosed()){
                if (serverIn.available() > 0) {
                    try {
                        if (serverIn.readObject() != null) {
                            Message input = (Message) serverIn.readObject();
                        }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
                if(hasMessages){
                    Message nextSend;
                    synchronized(messagesToSend){
                        nextSend = messagesToSend.pop();
                        hasMessages = !messagesToSend.isEmpty();
                    }
                    serverOut.writeObject(nextSend);
                    serverOut.flush();
                }
            }
            serverOut.close();
            serverIn.close();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void print(String message) {
        this.client.output(message);
    }
}
```

I know that the client is able to connect to the server, and both can get messages and successfully call the writeObject() method. However, the message never gets recieved. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you able to condense this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There's a lot of code here.

Comment: @slipperyseal There is no objection to 'trying to help', but there is certainly an objection to posting misinformation.

Comment: @slipperyseal And all it does instead is enter a 100%-CPU spin loop. Polling with a spin-loop is not superior to blocking, it is inferior in every way. And `available() > 0` doesn't guarantee there is an entire object present, so it can still block in `readObject()`.

Comment: @slipperyseal That one is equally pointless, as the thread can block in `writeObject()` or `flush()`. It should be split into two threads.

Comment: @EJP i agree it should be split into threads and dont like the design either. and i know it can block within the write and the read "mid-message". the intent of the available call appears to be that if no messages are incoming it would block indefinitely and not send the waiting outbound messages.

Comment: @slipperyseal The intent of the `available()` call can only be not to call `readObject()` if there isn't a complete object available to be read without blocking, but that's not what it does, so it is poinltless.

Comment: @EJP really i dont undestand removing it. if there are no messaging incoming but messages outgoing it will block on the read indefinitely. how is that a good chat program? using available > 0 would begin a read (even if it blocks but in practice you would expect the message to arrive within milliseconds, even if there are further blocks). unless you are saying the behaviour of available is different when using ObjectInputStream?

Comment: @slipperyseal Don't start that 'so are you saying' game. I am saying what I already said. It's not much use checking for at least one available byte when the objective is to read an entire object. Spin-looping is not better than blocking in any way, and especially not without a sleep.

Comment: @EJP the objective is to poll and not always read an object because the thread is needed to also poll for outgoing. I wrote small example and if you set skipAvail to true it blocks and never sends objects. otherwise it sends and receives fine. As mentioned I agree the whole implementation is a hack and should be on two threads with no avail checks or other shenanigans. i hope this example demonstrates what im trying to say. Also, i noticed you have to check available bytes on the underlying stream, not the object stream https://gist.github.com/slipperyseal/3a94987b144733069a1bbcf9efd5afa8

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!socket.isClosed()){
    if (serverIn.available() > 0) {
        try {
            if (serverIn.readObject() != null) {
                Message input = (Message) serverIn.readObject();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    if(hasMessages){
        Message nextSend;
        synchronized(messagesToSend){
            nextSend = messagesToSend.pop();
            hasMessages = !messagesToSend.isEmpty();
        }
        serverOut.writeObject(nextSend);
        serverOut.flush();
    }
}
```

This is all nonsense.

1. `isClosed()` returns true when *you* have closed the socket. Not when the peer disconnects.
2. Calling `available()` here and merely spin-looping while it is false is just literally a waste of time.
3. `ObjectInputStream.readObect()` only returns null if you send a null.
4. You are calling it twice, throwing the first object read away, and then trying to read the next object. So you are throwing away every odd-numbered object.

It should be more like this:

```
for (;;) {
        try {
            Message input = (Message) serverIn.readObject();
            // process input here
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            break;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    if(hasMessages){
        Message nextSend;
        synchronized(messagesToSend){
            nextSend = messagesToSend.pop();
            hasMessages = !messagesToSend.isEmpty();
        }
        serverOut.writeObject(nextSend);
        serverOut.flush();
    }
}
```

You should probably split this into a reading thread and a writing thread, as `writeObject()` and `flush()` can also block. Same remarks apply to the other place where you are using `isClosed()`, `available()`, testing for null, etc.

The `hasMessages` flag is also not going to work. It will remain false even though a message got added subsequently. It would be better to delete it and just rely on `messagesToSend.isEmpty()`, inside a synchronized block:

```
synchronized(messagesToSend){
    while (!messagesToSend.isEmpty()){
        Message nextSend = messagesToSend.pop();
        serverOut.writeObject(nextSend);
    }
}
serverOut.flush();
```